# OpenCV: Is there a way to decode qrcode in binary rather than string?

Tags: python, string, opencv, utf-8, qr-code

I am an experimentator hobbiist. I try to encode some binary into qrcode with the "qrcode" lib, and than decode it with cv2.
But cv2 decodes qrcodes in string rather than bytes, so as soon as it sees a 0x00 byte, it thinks that it's the null termination. So the encoded b'meta\x00\x00\xf3\x43myfile.txt' suddenly becomes just "meta" as string.
The encoding process was just with qrcode.make function, with bytes type parameter rather than string. The decoding process is below:

```py
from time import sleep, time
import cv2
# import chunker

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("chun/video.mp4")  # just for debugging. after success we'll make webcam.
detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
c=0
a=b''
while c!=32:
    _, img = cap.read()
    data, bbox, _ = detector.detectAndDecode(img)
    if a!=data:
        print(data)
        a=data
    #cv2.imshow("QR file receiver", img)
    #c=cv2.waitKey(1)
    # if c>-1: print(c)

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Can you give me an alternative to the qr.detectAndDecode function, or maybe a trigger to make it decode binary?
Thank you.

Comment: the api returns a `std::string` (c++) but docs say "UTF-8 encoded", which worries me. it ought to be translated to a python `bytes`. if opencv returns a python `str` instead of a `bytes`, please file an issue on the github. before you do that, check existing issues. maybe someone reported it already. maybe it's already fixed. you did not state the version of `opencv-python` you have installed.

Comment: yep, but I use the last version of cv2. And i'll check the issues, but i think there are millions of issues!